Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disable in container
Although I am running  Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) in container with base image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022 but in testing swagegr i face with error Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disable . how can i solved it?

The image  mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022 has already enable feature DTC so no need to enable it

I removed the  tag since this isn't a question about the SQL language. Perhaps you want to add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Why you gave me negative point?

I didn't do that. I removed a tag, that's all.
